# Binary is improperly signed error in cocoa app

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode8.2

I have created an archive of my cocoa app and placed in applications.
Now when i double click on it to run the app I get

**Error : Binary is improperly signed.**

M using **Developer certificate** and also **Team** is mentioned. However in **Provisioning profile** value is set as **None**

Comment: I created a new appid + new developer certificate and things were fine. surprising :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Adding a proper answer
```

I created a new App Id & a New Developer Certificate and things were fine. surprising :)